# isChecked() method always returns false - UIAUTOMATOR

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Her i am trying to check the AirPlaneMode checkbox whether it is all ready checkd or not if not then click. But it always click on the checkBox irrespective it is clicked or not :

Not able to figure it out where i am doing mistake.

Code:

```
public class AirPlaneModeHandler extends UiAutomatorTestCase{

    //private Context context;
    private int isAiplaneEnables;


    private void executeShellCommand(String paramString)
    {
        try 
        {           
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(paramString);
            p.waitFor();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            return ;
        } 
        catch (Exception localException){}      
    }



    public void startTest() {
           try {

               //isAiplaneEnables = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
               // toggleAiplaneMode();

               executeShellCommand("am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings");

               Thread.sleep(1000L);
               UiObject moreBtn = new UiObject(new UiSelector().index(4));
               if(moreBtn!=null) {
                    moreBtn.click();
               }

               Thread.sleep(1000L);

               UiObject object = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode"));
               if(object!=null) {
                   if(!object.isChecked())
                       object.click();
               }


             } catch (Exception localException) {
                // Log.d("POST", localException.getMessage());

              }

        }

}
```

Comment: Can you check UI Snapshot to see if you can find node details 'checkable' and 'checked' for UI Element with index 4?? Ideally for a checkbox, node details 'checkable' => true and 'check' => true/false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the isChecked() method Deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571244/is-the-ischecked-method-deprecated)

Comment: did you find the solution?