# Is the isChecked() method Deprecated

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

Is the `isChecked()` method Deprecated?

**I am coding for android UI and using UiAutomator Framework there this mathod is not displayed**

I am trying to validate one `uiobject` through `isChecked()` whether it is clicked or not.

from the below link i came to know it is Deprecated and now we should use `getValue()`.

```
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html
```

Code:

```
UiObject object = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode"));
if(object!=null) {
   if(!object.isChecked())
      object.click();
}
```

Here the problem is that the `getValue` method is not displaying i.e notavaible for use for me and `isChecked()` is always returning `false` to me.

Can any one give any suggestion to me.

Comment: *"Here the problem is that the getValue method is displaying for me and isChecked() is always returning false to me."* -  I've no idea what you mean by this sentence.  Please clarify.

Comment: sorry Stephen there was a typo error.

Comment: "is not available to me" is not a clear expression either. Has someone forbidden you to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to a wrong documentation.

Please check this [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html) for UIObject class documentation.

I don't think `isChecked()` is deprecated. It can be used only on an UI Object who's node detail `'checkable'=>true`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem except android studio wont even accept the method. I'm using a CheckedTextView and when I try to put

```
myCheckedTextView.isChecked()
```

android studio tells me "cannot resolve method isChecked()" but has plenty of other suggestions as expected.

suspiciously isChecked() is the only method in the documentation that has no description besides the signature.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#isChecked()